# How can I limit the numbers of links returned by paginate?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

The current `{{ $videos->links() }}` returns 13 links (including prev, next and ...), this is to much for a page I'm making. Is there a way to have it return less links? I couldn't find any way by looking at the source code.

Comment: Hi, I found this in source code: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Pagination/Presenter.php#L162
So you can change your concrete Presenter to show less pages. The default seems to be 7 (current, previous three, next three)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The majority of numbers relating to pagination are hard coded into the presenter. Like @AlexGuth has said in his comment you'll need to create a custom presenter so you can overload these methods and adjust the hard coded numbers.